# Amazon Athena - map column name to value with Java SDK

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-athena

After invoking get query results sdk method, I was wondering how should I map between the column name and the actual value in each row.
Can I assume that the column info list (under ResultSetMetadata) is ordered the same way each value is ordered in the list of Datum (under the Row)

if not, how can I map between the key (column name) and value (actual value of the column data in specific row)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. The documentation doesn't say so explicitly, but that's the way it works. It would be impossible for Athena to return the results to you in any other way because of the underlying storage format of the result (which is CSV).